# How to delete data from cassandra using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a table in cassandra keyspace named ap_auditor. I want to delete data from the table using spark sql. Could someone please guide me how to do that?

I have created spark session for querying cassandra table named trafficdata.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application").config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

Dataset loadTraffic = spark.read().format(SPARK_CASSANDRA_SQL_FORMAT)
    .options(ImmutableMap.of(TABLE, TRAFFIC_DATA_TABLE, KEYSPACE, APP_AUDITOR_KEYSPACE))
    .load();

Dataset trafficCols= loadTraffic.select("attributes.bytes-from-client","attributes.bytes-from-server")

loadTrafficData= trafficCols.withColumnRenamed("bytes-from-client", "bytesIn");

loadTrafficData.registerTempTable("trafficdata");
```

I saw a command `deleteFromCassandra` but that is for rdd. Is there any command for datasets?